# fill up gap on different DIV "Height" when float left

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to fill up the gap cause by the unequal height of different div height when using float left

Here is the before and what I currently have, the 2nd after image would be the desire results
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/901x507q90/538/OT5j3U.png

Comment: Please add the html and css code that you are using.

Comment: it is masonry plugin

Comment: for the css code it would be just floating left for all my div element generated using a for loop (php), and the height of the div would be relative to the contents.

Comment: no float left work only like new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is masonry plugin , you cant achieve this without that

see this link

[sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3](http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/)

[w3bits.com/css-masonry](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)

Comment: thanks man, that just what I wanted. Just a question can you do this without any plugin?

Comment: ok thanks guess i shall approach that plugin for my project! Thanks!

Comment: if you dont want to use plugin then create one but i guarantee it will be much harder than using already build one :)